# Pass data from a Ruby on Rails form to Joomla login form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, joomla

i would like to pass data like username and password from a form in my Ruby on Rails app to Joomla admin login form. I was thinking to use post method form but i can't figure it out. Can anyone give me some directions please?
I have tried a lot of things and search a lot of hours..

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Maybe Net::HTTP (bluit-in) http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP/Post.html

Answer (score 0):

Joomla! login (and most other forms) use a security token.  In order to login from an external application, you need to download the login form, grab the token i.e.

```
<input type="hidden" name="f9129bcc06dc6c1f3771a1f672308741" value="1" />
```

and insert it into your login form before you post.  Or lookup SSO Joomla and you'll find dedicated extensions, which however could make Joomla more vulnerable.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for you answer Riccardo and MrYoshiji. Let me ask on more thing please. I was wondering if there is a more simple way to just pass the data from my RoR app Database (SQLite3) ti the Joomla login form. With a link in my RoR app, maybe with an auto submit in my form. I didn't explain that i have username and password already in RoR database saved. Do i need an action in the controller of the model or something else. Do you know any tutorial about this? I am sorry form my english!